# Access - Can't format individual report fields, the entire column color changes

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I have a simple report that contains records and a chart based on a query. I don't have room for a legend in my chart, so I'm trying to color a field in the report's detail section to match the color of that record in the chart. I can color the chart like I want using VBA, but I cannot individually color a field value without coloring the entire column.

I've tried:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    If Me![Field1].Value = 32 Then
       Me![Field1].ForeColor = vbRed
    End If 
End Sub
```

The value is properly detected, but the entire Me![MyFieldName]'s column changes to red if 'SomeValue' is present.

[image: Entire column's color changes]

This problem has been driving me nuts for several days now and I'm about to give up. I was able to achieve my goal using VBA to write conditional formatting for each target value, but Access' maximum of 4 conditional formatting (if you include default) counts that solution out.

I've considered using hidden text boxes to store RGB values for each record, but I can't get conditional formatting to get the target color from another field, just values used to determine if a color needs to be applied.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Detail_Format` is the correct event to use. But you need an `Else` case in your code, to reset the format for all other values.

```
Dim lColor As Long

If Me![Field1].Value = 32 Then
    lColor = vbRed
' ElseIf Me![Field1].Value = 77 Then   ' etc
'     lColor = vbBlue
Else                                   ' default color
    lColor = vbBlack
End If

Me![Field1].ForeColor = lColor
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. Pretty embarrassing really, but thank you!